# Saying ביצה versus ביה

Tags: words, shemos-sacred-names, eggs, tractate-beitza

1) Why do people refer to the hebrew word for egg, ביצה, as ביה?

2) When one says ביה isn't he also saying part of G-d's Name?

Comment: the pronunciation I have heard is "bey-ah" instead of "bey-tzah"

Answer (score 9):

The Magain Avraham ([O.C. 156](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x540)) quoting the Yam Shel Shlomo says that it is to not say something disgusting (and it should be said in general, not specifically about the Mesechta name).

The Teferes Yisroel ([beginning of the Meschta](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37942&st=&pgnum=143&hilite=)) doesn't like that explanation and suggest instead it is to avoid confusing it with the word בצע which caused a mistake in Halacha at one point in the Talmud.

The word is ביעא, which is Aramaic for egg, not a reference to Hashem's name.

Answer (score 2):

1) The reason I have heard is that it is a matter of etiquette. בצים is a Hebrew euphemism for testicles, so some people, especially chasidim, are careful to use the Aramaic word for egg instead.

2) No, because the Aramaic word for egg is ביעא with a silent yud.

Comment: Note many people ([such as Rabbeinu Chananel](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=8&daf=2&format=pdf)) are not particular to translate it.

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe he pronounced it "gadol ha'eiya" :)

Comment: @DoubleAA I suspect this is what one of my litvish rebbeim would call chasidish nonsense, but I am way too polite and respectful to say any such thing. :)

Comment: @yEz Probably gedol since it's semichut.

Comment: @Double someone I know had this same haara. Problem is R' Chananel doesn't rhyme his other Masechta titles. At least not the ones I checked. So although he probably stripped out of his comfort zone for this cute little poem, it can also be a coincidence.

Comment: @Yitzchok My Uber Yeshivish Rosh Yeshiva had this same explanation.

Comment: As Yitzchak notes, the Hebrew word ביצה is used euphemistically to refer to a certain portion of the male anatomy. However, as with most Hebrew obscenity, this is likely derived from another Jewish language, such as Yiddish, which itself derives this usage from Russian. As Yitzchak further notes in the comments on his answer, his Litvisch rabbanim would likely refer to this usage as "Chasidish nonsense," due to a correlation between the Yiddish euphemism and the name of the masechta.

As an aside, I have heard from someone at Harvard Hillel that the masechta was known as "Yom-Tov."

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt All the rishonim, including the ones who never spoke any form of German, called it Yom Tov.

Comment: @user6591 Litvish !== Yeshivish, at least not always :)

Comment: @Yitzchok agreed, but Litvish does not exist outside of the Yeshiva system possibly since the times of Reb Yisroel Salanter. The only people who claim to be on the Litvish side of chasidic/misnagdic issue are members of the Yeshiva system. They would be shocked to learn they probably have more in common with Hassidism than Litvishism. I wonder which group the Gra would side with if he came back today. And I wonder what the Baal Shem would say about the people claiming to base their lives around his teachings. Its amusing in a way.

Comment: @Noach mi Frankfurt see Bechoros 40a, the first mishna.

Comment: @Yitzchak, the next question resultant from this thread should be "When did we start referring to this masechta as "Beitzah" rather than "Yom-Tov"

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, how do you know it was called "Yom-Tov" first?

Comment: @Yishai, see Yitzchak's comment to me.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, interesting claim, but the Rambam in Pirush HaMishnayos calls it [ביצה](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&st=&pgnum=51&hilite=).